# Uncaught TypeError: Object [Object object] has no method 'Sortable'

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie of using jQuery and UI.

I am using the Sortable method: `$('#div').Sortable()`

and got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [Object object] has no method 'Sortable'

Even I have included all of the jQuery files needed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./drag/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./drag/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./drag/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./drag/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./drag/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./drag/jquery.ui.sortable.min.js"></script>
```

So what is the problem here?

Comment: do you have a div or any other element with id="div"? Maybe it's something related to the selector

Comment: Post your HTML but at first glance: when you call the sortable method, do you use a Capital "S" because that would do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('#div').sortable()` with a lowercase S.